# What is this character saying in Latin?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, french

I was watching the latest *Asterix* movie. I know that people who know Latin sometimes don’t like the way it’s used in *Asterix*, but hear me out. There is this scene where the pirates are trying to get the Gauls to calm down.

The red-haired pirate says, “May we offer you a drink?”

Then the white-haired pirate says *something* in Latin.

And it must be partially reprehensible, because the red-haired pirate then basically mumbles, “Um, yeah, but you should be careful with that.”

I tried looking up the phase everywhere I could, I have not found it. I tried typing it phonetically in Google translate, but I got nothing that really made sense. So I’m wondering, as a last resort, if anyone here can figure out what this means.

Here’s the clip: https://youtu.be/rlERqf0E3Ds It’s only six seconds long.

In the original *Asterix*, none of the Latin was written for the comics. The author, René Goscinny, always said the same thing when someone tried to correct his Latin: that he didn’t know any Latin at all and that he’d copied the phrase from the “proverbs and sayings” section of the dictionary. (“Les pages roses du Petit Larousse.”) But maybe, because this is a new and recent story, the phrase is not a quotation and that it’s written to be relevant to the situation. In any case, I can’t figure it out.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like **bonum vinum laetificat cor hominis**, with a French accent. "Good wine cheers a man's heart."

It's not an uncommon phrase, inspired by [Ecclesiasticus 40:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ecclesiasticus+40%3A20&version=VULGATE) (part of the Deuterocanon).

Comment: It worth noting that stripping this out of context and considering the grammar alone, this might be rendered as *man's heart enriches good-wine* which is really not so far fetched as one might suppose, as the judgment (and the very taste itself!) of people tend to be effected by their "hearts" (prejudices, and even their mood.)

Comment: Les pages roses agree with your text, but add the full quotation attrib. **Eccle'siastique XL 20.** Wine and music rejoice the heart: but the love of wisdom is above them both

Comment: @Hugh Apparently Ecclésiastique and Ecclesiastes are different books and something got confused along the way. Ecclesiasticus (Ecclésiastique) has the exact quote.

Comment: Oh, it's not actually the exact same quote, I guess. Still a lot closer than Ecclesiastes.

Comment: Thanks! I got _some_ words right, but not nearly enough. This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Hugh I used to have a Larousse AND a Robert, but these days, I am separated from my physical books. I would not have expected the phrase to come from a biblical quotation, and the film takes place in 50 BCE. That's my bad for being too literal.